# Error: Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers, lenovo-laptop

My system is getting the following error and warning message whenever I do any high performance task:

> Display driver igfx stopped responding and has successfully recovered.

My system configuration is follows:

- Lenovo Flex2
- 8 GB RAM
- NVIDIA GEFORCE 2 GB
- DEDICATED RAM
- OS : Windows 10

Due to this, my system keeps getting stuck.  I've tried lots of things found by googling, with no success.

Comment: I might help to include what you tried.  It will save people from suggesting the same things again.

Comment: update the Intel GPU driver

Comment: Since you have NVidia graphics hardware, why are you using "igfx", which is an Intel graphics driver?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using the latest stable drivers from Intel (This was back in ~December.) After a long search, I found a large forum thread of people having the same issues . One recommendation by someone from Intel was to try their latest Beta driver, which can be found [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25749).

Since using the driver from here, I haven't seen the message since and it's been perfectly stable. That said, before trying that, I would suggest creating a [System Restore Point](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/create-a-system-restore-point) and trying the drivers from Lenovo from [here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/flex-series/flex-2-15-notebook-lenovo/downloads/DS103743), or at least getting a copy of it in case you need to revert.

The thread I saw previously was [here](https://communities.intel.com/thread/77855).

Comment: Thank you for the tips, i did all these. but still thee issue persists. Please let me know if you find anything new